# Database trigger to update a row on parent table after child table has been updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

First time creating a Database trigger. I have a child table that when its cost column is updated, I need its parent table to also update its cost column to reflect the change.

Here is my sorry attempt so far. That's obviously not working. I am having a problem figuring out how to extract the total cost as a variable and store it in the parent table.

My current approach assumes a static id vaule at the moment. I am not entirely sure how to dynamically determine the id value of the row that was updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ParentCost_Update
ON ChildTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 

AS 
SELECT SUM(Cost) AS TotalCost FROM ChildTable where parent_id=2080

UPDATE ParentTable
    SET Cost=TotalCost
    where id=parent_id;

GO
```

This current script is returning an error

*Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ParentCost_Update, Line 9
Invalid column name 'TotalCost'.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful in triggers, in that there could be more than one row updated. Therefore, you need to do row-based handling.

To obtain the newly inserted / updated row, use the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo rows.

You will almost certainly also going to need to implement a `deleted` trigger as well, viz, if a row is removed from a child table that the parent will need to be recalculated.

Here's a row based take, using a CTE to map your two-step process above , as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ParentCost_Update
ON ChildTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   WITH cteParentsAffected AS
   (
      SELECT ins.parent_id
      FROM inserted ins

      UNION

      SELECT del.parent_id
      FROM deleted del
   )
   , cteTotal AS
   (
      SELECT ct.parent_id, SUM(ct.Cost) AS TotalCost 
      FROM ChildTable ct
      INNER JOIN cteParentsAffected par
      ON ct.parent_id = par.parent_id
      GROUP BY ct.parent_id
   )
  UPDATE pt
      SET Cost=cte.TotalCost
      FROM ParentTable pt
      INNER JOIN cteTotal cte
      ON id=cte.parent_id;
GO
```

[With a SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2502/5)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Update parenttable set total= (select sum(total) from childtable c where c.id= parent table.id)
Where id in (select id from inserted)
```

Change the table and column names.